# Adding a new property to an object type without runtime code

Tags: typescript

```
type FormerActions =
  | {
      type: "ACTION_A"
      payload: string
    }
  | {
      type: "ACTION_B"
      payload: number
    }

type Converter = ...

type ModifiedActions = Converter<FormerActions, "group", "DOMAIN">

//should output
type ModifiedActions =
  | {
      group: 'DOMAIN'
      type: "ACTION_A"
      payload: string
    }
  | {
      group: 'DOMAIN'
      type: "ACTION_B"
      payload: number
    }
```

I want to write a `Converter` "type function" that takes the arguments as listed above and outputs a type equal (or structurally equal) to `ModifiedActions`.

I know I can probably used mapped types to add the property and maybe conditional types can work on the distributive `|` thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
type Id<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K]}  
type Converter<T, K extends string, V> = T extends any ? Id<Record<K, V> & T> : never
```

maybe?

[image]

The idea is indeed to [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) over the type `T` with `T extends any ? ...`, and then to merge each constituent with `Record<K, V>` from the [standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.8.2/lib/lib.d.ts#L1364).  Finally, I used `Id<T>` which just walks through a type and outputs it as key-value pairs.

All that being said, that type is essentially equivalent to just `Record<K, V> & T`, I think.  The distributing and merging is just to be pretty (and maybe avoid some odd edge cases, although it adds some too.)

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: If you do the following, you will also get nicer names when you hover over the type (you eliminate the intersection types) : `type Converter<T, K extends string, V> = T extends any ? { [P in keyof Id<Record<K, V> & T>]: Id<Record<K, V> & T>[P] } : never`

Comment: Isn't that just `Id<Id<Record<K, V>  & T>>`?  I don't see what it changes.  When I hover over with mine I get the output without intersections (that's what the one `Id<>` does).  Confused.

Comment: In your version if I hover over I get the flowing : `type ModifiedActions = Id<Record<"group", "DOMAIN"> & {
    type: "ACTION_A";
    payload: string;
}> | Id<Record<"group", "DOMAIN"> & {
    type: "ACTION_B";
    payload: number;
}>` with my version I get `type ModifiedActions = {
    group: "DOMAIN";
    type: "ACTION_A";
    payload: string;
} | {
    group: "DOMAIN";
    type: "ACTION_B";
    payload: number;
}` Functionally the same but the second is marginally easier to read :)

Comment: I also came up with `export type AddProp2<T, K> = T extends any ? T & K : never`, I can just pass the object to the second parameter.
Titian's answer is somehow downgrading the objects to `{ [string] : any }` here. Sad, it would be great to get cleaner syntax.
So in the end it's quite simple but I never found out that I can just throw an `T extends any` for the mapped type :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Not sure what's different in our environments; I edited the above with a screenshot of my VSCode inspection of `ModifiedActions`.  